# SQL Server 2008 : see how a table column is calculated

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am new to this so...

I have a table that I will call "tableA" it has a column in it that is a calculation from somewhere else in the database that I will call "n_orders".

I want to know where the int in that column is come from. Is there a way to do this? It is a table not a view. This column is not a key and is not labeled as a identity column.

Comment: How do you know that the value comes from "n_orders"? Where have you seen that "n_orders" is used?

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS, you can view the detailed properties in the Table Designer (right-click table, Design - then view the column properties.  Or, right-click the table and Script Table As -> Create -> to New Query Window and see the column definition there.

This assumes that the column is a computed column (which I assumed from your use of "calculated").

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you are trying to find the calculation used for a column, you can get this with the help of below query.

```
    SELECT DEFINITION
    FROM SYS.computed_columns 
    WHERE name = 'n_orders'
    AND OBJECT_ID('tableA') = OBJECT_ID
```